# IP permission in .XSLT file for seeing XML(WSDL) file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

I have a XML(WSDL) file that I want to manage it by using .XSLT file. I want to set IP permission in my .XSLT file for seeing some part of WSDL that some restricted IPs can see some part of my WSDL.
I have this WSDL :

```
          <wsdl:types>
        ...
      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message>
        ...
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap">
         <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
             <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
             <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
             <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
         </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
            <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        ...
      </wsdl:portType>

  ....
```

This is my .xslt file:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetISD']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want to set IP permission that for example : 10.10.10.1 can't see this part of my WSDL :

```
 <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
    <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `Authorization` at operation level to achieve this? When implementing web services operation, define `roles` and users with valid permissions are able to access certain operations. By just restricting their view, you'd still have to deal with unauthorized access to service

Comment: Can you explain more about it?